# mysql sync two tables from 2 databases

Tags: mysql

I have a query . I have two tables on two different servers .Both the tables have the same structure . The master table on one server gets updated on a daily basis , so i want a cron job or a php script cron to update the second slave table on a different server . 
I have seen a lot of scripts but none resolved my requirements .

Comment: Updated in which way? Structure, Data,.. how should it be updated, why didn't a lot of scripts resolve your requirements. What are your requirements.

Comment: its mysql..its not about the structure..its the data which keeps increasing ..i want a php cron job to do it ..but i dont know how to go about it in the simplest and most optimized manner . I dont want to select the data from the master table and loop them untill they are inserted in the slave table .That takes too much time .

Comment: so i would appreciate if iam suggested with some optimized way of doing it

Comment: It's not clear what you're exact requirements are, but perhaps you want to look into [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replication.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't believe you didn't find a suitable script to do this. Depending on server-to-server bandwidth and connectivity, and table data size, you can:

- directly transfer the whole table:

  ```
  mysqldump [options] sourcedatabase tablename \
    | mysql [options] --host remoteserver --user username ...
  ```
- transfer the table with MySQL compression

  ```
  # same as above, mysql has the "-C" flag
  ```
- transfer using SSH encryption and compression; mysql is executed remotely

  ```
  mysqldump [options] sourcedatabase tablename \
    | ssh -C user@remoteserver 'mysql [options]'
  ```
- transfer using intermediate SQL file and rsync to transfer only modifications

  ```
  mysqldump [options] sourcedb tbl > dump.sql
  rsync [-z] dump.sql user@remoteserver:/path/to/remote/dump.sql
  ssh user@remoteserver "mysql [options] < /path/to/remote/dump.sql"
  ```

The above are all simple table overwrites, remote data is LOST and replaced by the master copy. The mysqldump-plus-rsync-plus-ssh runs in a time roughly proportional to modifications, which means that if you have a 10-GB SQL dump and add a dozen INSERTS, the transfer stage will need at most a couple seconds to synchronize the two SQL files.

To optimize the insert stage too, either you go for full MySQL replication, or you will need a way to identify operations on the table in order to replicate them manually at sync time. This may require alterations to the table structure, e.g. adding "last-synced-on" and "needs-deleting" columns, or even introduction of ancillary tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one simple solution - [Data Synchronization tool](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-synchronization.html) in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).

1. Create Data Comparison project that would compare and synchronize two tables on two different MySQL servers.
2. Run application in command line mode using created Data Comparison project document (*.dcomp file).